# Based on selected language, the whole app / website should change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to change language based on the user selection.

I have tried Localization, internalization, i18n.

The examples I have seen use static data which first has to declare and based on the language it is changing.

My data is completely dynamic so how do you do it all at once based on the language selection.

Comment: Based on what you have described you should use a translation service and recommending services/resources/software is off-topic on this site.

Comment: Thank You. Instead of voting down, providing answer will be great help if anyone knows.

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for? A magical script that translates all of your application data? Chrome/Chromium browsers has this feature. As I have stated what you need is a translation service.

Comment: Already as i said Thank you for you comment. Once again thanks. I am trying for that. And i never asked for the magic scripts and you are taking in the wrong way.

Comment: You can use https://angular-translate.github.io/ for app side translation but for dynamic stuff you will have to manage that from API side. You can pass language code with request so that you can know in which language the response should be.

Comment: Thanks @HardikVaghani. So that mean i have to use some paid version for transalation

Comment: https://angular-translate.github.io/ isn't paid.

Comment: But that is working only for the static data what we define. Am I right..?. Or esle we can work with dynamic stuff also @HardikVaghani

Comment: Yes for static keys it works. Not sure about dynamic stuff.

Comment: That what i said. I want to change dynamically but not static. But thanks @HardikVaghani for your time